# Using Oracle database with the encoding UTF-8

Tags: python, oracle, utf-8, oracle10g

I have an oracle database which is encoded to US-ASCII because when I run the command `print db.encoding`, US-ASCII is the response.

My problem is that I have some special characters in the database like "ç" and "ã" and when I make some queries, these special characters are returned as question marks (?).

I need to encode the data as UTF-8 but I don't know how. I've already used methods like encode() and unicode() but nothing works.

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've resolved my problem with the command below before the database connection:

```
import os
os.environ["NLS_LANG"] = ".UTF8"
```

Answer (score 0):

You must create the database in Oracle with `NATIONAL CHARACTER SET` clause. Check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch6unicode.htm) post on how to achieve this.